# Problemas con consultas y listar información en tabla desde SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, ssms

Tengo buen rato trantando de resolver lo siguiente

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

pero no doy con el resultado correcto, ya Google, revise documentación pero nada, mi codigo es

```
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    
        <table class="table tbl-bordered table-reponse">
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Usuario</td>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Accion</td>
                <td>Accion</td>
            </tr>

            <?php
            
            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
            $ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($con, $consulta);

            $i = 0;

            while($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($ejecutar)){
                $id = $fila['id'];
                $usuario = $fila['usuario'];
                $password = $fila['password'];
                $email = $fila['email'];
                $i++;

                
            }
            ?>

            <tr align="center">
                <td><?php print $id;       ?></td>
                <td><?php print $usuario;  ?></td>
                <td><?php print $password; ?></td>
                <td><?php print $email;    ?></td>
                <td><a href="formulario.php?editar = <?php print $id; ?>"></a>Editar</td>
                <td><a href="formulario.php?eliminar = <?php print $id; ?>"></a>Eliminar</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme de alguna manera, con algun blog, documentacion ¡Porfavor!

Comment: El código se comparte como texto. Por favor, edita tu pregunta. Lo otro: suponemos que usas sql server? (es para que uses la etiqueta correspondiente). Sobre tu problema, esos warnings están avisando más o menos claro lo que estás haciendo mal. `$conn` no parece tener una conexión, hazle debug

Comment: Sí. de hecho debe ser como texto pero luego me marca que es mucho código, por eso lo puse como imagen, $conn si tiene conexion porque en en insertar datos en la BD si me permite pero consultar y mostrar en pantalla no...

Comment: Hazle debug porque estás cerrando la conexión más arriba. No supongas. Y si te dice que es mucho, entonces pon lo relevante solamente

Answer (score 1):

No se exactamente que haces mal pero el problema debe de estar en el $conn.
ahora algo que si te puedo señalar es tu while en la consulta, si vas a crear un while asegurate que los campos de la tabla estén abajo, porque si muestras las variables cuando termines el while solo te dará 1 solo resultado.
ejemplo:

```
<?php
while (consulta...){
   $nombre =  ...
   $apellido= ...
   $etc...
<?
<tr>
   <td> <?php echo $nombre; <? </td>
   <td> etc... </td>
   ...
</tr>
<?php 
} //cerramos while 
?>
```

bueno hay maneras mas limpias de hacerlo pero lo hice simple